# Custom list column validation in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-list

I´ve encountered a little problem when I want to validate my fields (columns) in my custom list in Sharepoint 2013.

I give you an example:

I have a custom form made in Infopath with several fields and 2 date and time fields. One is lets call it "StartDate" which never changes and the other is "EndDate" and that date changes. And when I have "createListItem" form, the "EndDate" validation must be "StartDate+365days", that is pretty easy to do. But when I need to edit list item, I need another validation of "EndDate", this time "EndDate+365days". Is there any possible way to do it without programming? I tried it using additional fields and using calculated type of fields but was not able to achieve of what I want?

Any suggestions? Maybe someone here was trying to do same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do different validations for a same field on InfoPath form views. InfoPath rules run for an InfoPath form, not a special view. If we change a rule in a view, the rules on other views will be changed.

For your requirement, I suggest you use JavaScript code with `PreSaveAction()` function to achieve it.
[SharePoint Form Validation Using JavaScript + jQuery](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/9279/sharepoint-form-validation-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: ok thanks, I will look into it :)

Comment: if my reply helps you, please remember to accept it as answer. :)